# Crashing by executing ARCore in Pixel

Tags: android, google-project-tango, arcore

trying to execute the example app in pixel but  I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.Initialize(android.content.Context) (tried Java_com_google_atap_tango_TangoJNINative_Initialize and Java_com_google_atap_tango_TangoJNINative_Initialize__Landroid_content_Context_2)
    at com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.Initialize(Native Method)
    at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.<init>(Tango.java:385)
    at com.google.ar.core.TangoWrapper.createInstance(TangoWrapper.java:32)
    at com.google.ar.core.Session.bindTangoService(Session.java:425)
    at com.google.ar.core.Session.resume(Session.java:153)
    at com.google.ar.core.examples.java.helloar.HelloArActivity.onResume(HelloArActivity.java:136)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6786)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3407)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3470)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2733)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: make sure your phone is on the supported list also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs:
You have to download and install the ARCore Services.

> You must use a supported, physical device. ARCore does not support virtual devices such as the Android Emulator. To prepare your device:
>
> Enable developer options
> Enable USB debugging
> Download the [ARCore Service](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases/download/sdk-preview/arcore-preview.apk), then install it with the following adb command:
> `adb install -r -d arcore-preview.apk`

See: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/getting-started Prepare your device

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to Install Tango core.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.tango&hl=zh_TW